# how to back from "\My-Github\my-website (main)" to "\My-Github\my-website (main --> origin)"

Tags: github, cmder

i did mistake that i write wrong mistake in cmder
the status now is "λ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean"
how to return to " \My-Github\my-website (main --> origin)"

"git origin "
i tried that but no response

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.